# Data Entry Form Project

Tags: 7, forms

Need input on Data Entry project using Drupal 7. The requirements are as follows:

1. A user logs in and enters sale transactions (Name, address, item, price ...) multiple times.
2. A user can view/modify their own transactions.

Does Drupal 7 offer a solution and how?

Comment: Looks like project Entityform is what you are looking for